# Apt pretends to be fully updated, but libxml2 will not update past 2.9.10, even though the latest version is 2.9.14?

Tags: raspberry-pi, debian, raspbian, libxml2, apt

I am updating a Raspberry Pi running Debian 10. Specifically, I need to update the package `libxml2` from version 2.9.4 (very old!) to 2.9.14, in order to protect myself against [CVE-2022-23308](https://nvd.nist.gov/vuln/detail/CVE-2022-23308). To do this, I had to update Debian 10 (buster) to Debian 11 (bullseye), which allowed me to update a lot of packages several versions ahead. However, I am only partway to the newest version, but apt prevents me from updating further?

To update as far as I have now, I did the following in this order, following [these instructions](https://debian-handbook.info/browse/stable/sect.dist-upgrade.html):

1. Updated `/etc/apt/sources.list` and all files in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d` to replace all instances of "buster" with "stable"
2. `sudo apt update`
3. `sudo apt upgrade`
4. `sudo apt full-upgrade`
5. `sudo apt autoremove`
6. `sudo apt clean`
7. `sudo apt dist-upgrade` (nothing was updated)

Now, when I run `lsb_release -a`, I get:

```
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Raspbian
Description:    Raspbian GNU/Linux 11 (bullseye)
Release:        11
Codename:       bullseye
```

so I know I have the latest version. And when I run `apt list --all-versions libxml2`, I get:

```
Listing... Done
libxml2/stable,now 2.9.10+dfsg-6.7+deb11u2 armhf [installed]
```

That was all context - here's the weird part. `sudo apt update` says that all packages are up to date - however I know that's false, because you can see newer versions on Debian's website [right here](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/libxml2/-/releases), and they've been out for a while, at least a year.

**The Actual Question:** Why does `apt` pretend it has the latest version, when it clearly doesn't? With Debian updated to the latest version, I should be able to get the latest version of everything else, right? Am I missing some other piece? How can I update past this point to get libxml2 2.9.14? If I need to switch to a different distro or some other major change, I will, but that's not ideal :/

Thank you so much for your time and help!

Comment: apt does not always contain the latest versions of libraries. If you need the latest version, compile from source yourself.

Comment: according to [this website](https://packages.debian.org/search?suite=default&section=all&arch=any&searchon=names&keywords=libxml2), the latest version available on Buster is the one you have. Only Bookworm(testing) has the newest version.

Comment: Compiling from source is a great idea! Thank you! That did bring up it's own issues (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72623173/using-a-compiled-from-source-library-that-is-a-newer-version-of-a-preexisting-li), but hey! Still progress! How can I accept this an answer or give you reputation?

Answer (score 0):

I have tried the following, it didn't help with the error but I guess it did update the whole list:

```
# dnf clean all
# dnf check
# dnf check-update
# dnf update
```

If there is still a problem then try with "dnf update --nobest" command. Hope this helps